# Extract Information from Tkinter drawing

Tags: python, tkinter, draw

I am currently trying to script something that allows me to "draw numercial Input".

The idea is to use tkinters `create_line` in combination with tkinters capability to `bind` methods to events in order to get some drawing that has then to be decoded into x and y values in order to serve as input for another program.

Now the first part is no problem, here is a minimal code to do so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *

global x_0, y_0

def draw(event):
    global x_0, y_0
    if x_0 and y_0:
        w.create_line(x_0, y_0, event.x, event.y)
    x_0 = event.x
    y_0 = event.y

def letgo( event):
    global x_0, y_0
    x_0, y_0 = None, None

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
w.pack()
x_0 = None
y_0 = None
w.bind('<B1-Motion>', draw)
w.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', letgo)

mainloop()
```

And, running this, evidently the Drawing is saved somewhere, but how do I get it back in array form?

Kind Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "back in array form"? It was never in array form. I think you need to work on this a little more (like making it save the drawing) before asking how to get it back — because that will depend entirely on how it stored and saved.

Comment: do you want to get each pixel's value on the visible canvas? I suggest you take a screenshot using `pillow` and then use `pillow` to get that array

Comment: Somewhere the information has to be existing allready. Of course I could do a screenshot and check where black pixels are, what I am confused about is where the module stores the info and how I can access it. If it can be viewed it can also be accessed.

Comment: seemingly the closes you can get is a `PostScript`, using the `postcript` method on `tk.Canvas` (you can find some docs on it [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) (just scroll a bit down till you see it))

Comment: Thanks, that website is a rich source of useful information!

Comment: If you just want the x, y coordinates of the line endpoints, why don't you just save them in your event handler functions? You can put them in "array" format then.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Comments by users I can post an answer to my question here, but the real answer is the comments.

The hint to use post script was good but the website provided me with information which seems to give me what is closest to an answer to my question.

The canvas method `find_all` allows one to find the IDs of all objects on the canvas. The canvas method `coords(ID)` allows one to get the coordinates, in this example coordinate pairs (start and endpoint of linesegments).

In this minimal code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *

global x_0, y_0

def draw(event):
    global x_0, y_0
    if x_0 and y_0:
        w.create_line(x_0, y_0, event.x, event.y)
    x_0 = event.x
    y_0 = event.y

def letgo(event):
    global x_0, y_0
    all_segment_ids = w.find_all()
    all_segments = []
    for isegment in range(len(all_segment_ids)):
        all_segments.append(w.coords(isegment))
    print(all_segments)
    x_0, y_0 = None, None

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
w.pack()
x_0 = None
y_0 = None
w.bind('<B1-Motion>', draw)
w.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', letgo)

mainloop()
```

The `list` 'all_segments' contains all 4-tuples that describe the picture.

The script will grow in complexity if other objects are added to the canvas, they wil have to be identified and excluded.

With numpy's `assarray` this list can be converted to an array.

Thanks for all the support.